# A site seems to be mirroring Super User

Tags: support, questions

There is a [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/13942/paint-net-equivalent-for-linux) that seems to be copied at `earthwithsun.com/questions/13942/paint-net-equivalent-for-linux`

If you scroll down to the bottom of earthwithsun.com you'll see another striking likeness; 7903 of them.

"earthwithsun.com" is obviously mirroring superuser.com. They
must have some script for copying the questions, comments and answers. I do not see any links back to Super User, or any other notifications of where the content is taken from.

Is this a concern? Is there anything that can be done about it, and should we care?

Comment: Known offender: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules/181916#181916 Usually you'd report as described here, but I doubt this is necessary for this site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: Nice, did not know about that system, but as you said, that site is already reported there. Thanks! Would you like to make an answer so I can accept it, or do you think I should just delete the question?

Comment: Lots of sites also mirror AskUbuntu.com (questions, answers, and usernames).

Comment: @Ludwik : That's easy : the databases of all stack exchange sites can be downloaded for free at data.SE *(weekly updates)*. That's said, they are provided for statistical purpose, so I don't know if mirroring is OK.

Comment: Since everything posted is under a creative commons license, I believe it's allowed with some restrictions. This site doesn't give any sort of attribution though

Comment: See also: http://www.xiabox.com/ http://www.goodstuffer.net/

Comment: These people have no shame, do they?

Comment: It's so nice to give us (and Google) proper links to help them going up to the top page of all search engines. :)  And for that, stack (which already ranks great) will give extra credit to them.

Comment: It's worth noting, at least on xiabox, that they include a copyright on the bottom of their page. Since it's a copyright in clear violation of SE's CC license, SE can press criminal charges for copyright violation and file a civil suit as well. Not that that's likely to happen.... but the legal rights are there.

Comment: IDK if this is new, but the site you linked to in the question (http://earthwithsun.com/) has links on the side, proclaiming [Server questions and answers](http://www.xiabox.com/) and [Wordpress questions and answers](http://www.goodstuffer.net/).....haven't checked, but these sound like the same thing for Server Fault and Wordpress.SE

Answer (score 3):

Those sites are scraping content from Super User, as they are allowed to, so long as they [follow the rules of attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/):

> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

If you find a site that is copying, but fails to follow the above four minor steps, please [report that site to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) and they will take it from there.